# Android multi RecyclerView with viewPager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

There are my apps structure:
"A" activity has a EditText, it allows user input a number
If user input "3". B activity will generate 3 tab with viewPager.
Each tab will display a single RecyclerView.

So, I need to create a array of arraylist to store the item

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> list=new ArrayList<>();
```

[image]

When user input "3":
it will new 3 list

```
list.add(new ArrayList());
```

3 RecyclerView will share some adapter.
I create the FAButton. to insert new item into specific tab.

I found a problem. When i insert item into specific list. It will insert correctly. But, the recyclerView will not update immediately.
I need to swipe the viewpager and swipe. New item will display.

I observe that when user swipe viewpager. The adapter of recyclerView will recreate.

I need to new a adapter to all recyclerView?
3 recyclerView = 3 adapter = 3 arraylist

ViewPager code:
[Code](https://codeshare.io/9pUgk)

RecyclerView
[Code](https://codeshare.io/xxl2P)

Comment: can you give source code of adapter and activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i fixed this issues.

When i generate the Tabs
For example, i need to generate 6 tabs + 6 page + 6 recycler view
The viewpager won't create 6 adapters of recyclerview for those 6 recycler view.

I need to force to set the adapter when i insert item into corresponding list.

Firstly,
In the ViewPager adapter, i need to set tag to the recyclerview

```
mrecyclerView.setTag("view"+position);
```

In the insert procedure, i need to get the tag.

```
RecyclerView view = (RecyclerView)mViewPager.findViewWithTag("view"+mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
view.setAdapter(new RecycleViewListAdapter(context,mViewPager.getAdapter()).list.get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()));
view.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Finally, i can fixed this issues